# Unable to extract data from database to UI - Laravel

Tags: laravel

I've just started out learning web development. I've been trying to extract data from my database to the UI but I'm facing an error.
I have an Admin dashboard where I want to extract some data 'investment ideas' from table 'investment_ideas_tables'. From reference online, I've made the following changes.

Created a new InvestmentIdeasController.php file in Admin folder. Created the following function.
Table Name is 'investment_ideas_tables'

```
class InvestmentIdeasController extends Controller
{
    //
    public function index()
    {
        $investment_ideas = DB::table('investment_ideas_tables')->get();
        return view('dashboard', ['investment_ideas' => $investment_ideas]);
    }
}
```

In the UI blade file named 'dashboard.blade.php', I entered the following code in my table.
Column name is 'investment_idea'

```
@foreach ($investment_ideas as $row)
                <tr>
                    <td> 1</td>
                    <td> {{ $row -> investment_idea }} </td>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                @endforeach
```

In web.php file, included the following routing.

```
Route::get('dashboard', 'InvestmantIdeasController@index');
```

I'm unsure of the first attribute in the routing statement. Currently, I'm getting the error:

> Route [admin.dashboard] not defined. (View: /Users/vinayak/Documents/AWS Team 5/InvestmentApplication/resources/views/welcome.blade.php)

I don't understand how this path is coming up. I'm confused with the steps. Can you please help  and point out the mistake I am making?

Comment: try this: ``Route::get('dashboard', 'InvestmantIdeasController@index')->name('admin.dashboard'); `` also do ``php artisan optimize:clear``

Comment: It seems you forgot to give the `admin.dashboard` name to your route. Applying the desired name should do the trick, something like `Route(...)->name('admin.dashboard')`. Another thing, the error states that you're accessing the `welcome.blade.php` file which is not expected according to your code.

Comment: Check the documentation for how Named Routes work: https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/routing#named-routes. Your issue is in `welcome.blade.php`, where you're probably calling `route('admin.dashboard')`, but you didn't include that code in your question... If the documentation doesn't help, please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/75867908/edit) with the contents of `welcome.blade.php`

Answer (score 0):

The admin.dashboard route is not defined in the welcome.blade.php file.

You display the data in the dashboard.blade.php file.

Are you sure you GET the /Users/vinayak/Documents/AWS Team 5/InvestmentApplication/resources/views/dashboard.blade.php view?

**OR**

You just forgot to name your route

```
Route::get('dashboard', 'InvestmantIdeasController@index')->name('admin.dashboard');
```